# Turn all the url in html link tags without converting any other links whit javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a REST service that deliver strings with text and links. Within strings may be url but also links already formatted with HTML link tags.

I'm looking for a way to turn all URL into html link without changing any of the existing link tags.

I used this function but it does just half of the job cause it turns the urls inside the href attribute of the existing link tags

```
var text = "Test linktag: <a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>  some other text" + "<br>" +
            "Test url:  http://www.google.com some other text";
function urlify(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    var text1 = text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
    var exp2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    return text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
}

var result = urlify(text)
// result will give:
// Test linktag: <a target='_blank' href='<a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>'>Google</a>  some other text<br>Test url:  <a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a> some other text
```

Comment: can u make fiddle for what u have tried so far

Comment: You have to get your function to look for existing `a` tags and either remove them (the simplest way but will lose any attributes like `target` already present) or not add a new one.

Comment: @SunKnight0 loosing target attribute won't be a problem cause every link in my app has target="_blank" attribute.

Comment: Then just remove all instances of <a*> and </a> from your text before adding the new tags

Comment: @SunKnight0 it adds to many variables to the plate.. I believe the best thins i can do is to try some libraries. The best i found work like a charm:
https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tag myself as a duplicate cause the question was (obviously) already asked and there's already a proper answer.

That answer isn't a solution but it's the best way to face my problem:

[How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from this link

```
<div tabIndex="0" title="People Picker" class="ms-inputuserfield">Administrator</div>
```

[Dynamacily add anchor tag](http://jsfiddle.net/QUcux/)